# Chrome TTS web page reader that reads with no text selected

Tags: chrome, speech-synthesis

I'm looking for a web page text to speech (tts) extension for Chrome that doesn't require first selecting the text, and doesn't require copying, pasting, emailing or saving the file first.

What I want is something that It just takes a page as it is, then when you tell it to start reading, it just starts with the first sentence or the one you select (all or part of), then highlights each sentence on the web page as it's reading it and scrolls accordingly.

It would be nice it it had media control buttons (back, forward, pause, resume, play, stop, even record)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found just what I wanted 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-page-reader-tts-text/anafkmjpnlnmmengalcgbkkplfpeckia

It does all that I specified

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried it as I use Linux, but google themselves provide [ChromeVox](http://www.chromevox.com/) for chrome on windows, MacOS, and chromebooks.

Comment: Thank you; this is nice compared to other extensions. However, like other screen readers, it requires first selecting the text. As it reads, it doesn't highlight the sentence being read. There are no controls for pitch, speed, or next / previous sentence. I'm thinking now what I'm looking for doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

For that I build [Intelligent Speaker](https://intelligent-speaker.com). Still no text highlighting - but maybe someday this will be implemented.

Comment: The one I use (the selected answer) does it. I built it because it didn't exist. None of the other readers do it, because it's too hard to code. But I did it.